# How to reference intermediate dataframe when method chaining in pandas?

Tags: python, r, pandas, dplyr

When chaining dataframe operations in dplyr, it is possible to use operations that anonymously depend on the current dataframe, as a trivial example:

```
data.frame(x=3) %>% filter(x == 3) %>% mutate(x = x/sum(.$x))
```

Here I can do an operation on the dataframe itself up to a chained operation by referencing "."

What is the equivalent way to do this in pandas with method chaining? Is it possible without defining intermediate variables?

Answer (score 3):

In python

```
df[df.W01.eq(3)].assign(x=df[df.W01.eq(3)].W02.transform(lambda x : x/sum(x)))
Out[873]: 
   W01  W02         x
0    3    1  0.333333
1    3    1  0.333333
2    3    1  0.333333
```

Explanation:

```
df[df.W01.eq(3)] : filter(x == 3)

.assign(x=df[df.W01.eq(3)].W02.transform(lambda x : x/sum(x))) : mutate(x = x/sum(.$x))
```

---

Data Input

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'W01': [3,3,3,2], 'W02': [1,1,1,999]})
```

Comment: And pandas mirrors base R: `transform(df[df$W01==3,], X = W02/sum(W02))`...good to see a fellow SO user who dabbles in both!

Comment: @Parfait , just think R and Python are the same ~ :-)

Comment: .assign accept lambdas for just this reason FYI; you are repeating the selection

Comment: This doesn't seem like it generalizes that well because it relies on repeating all the transformations within the assign operation. That's fine in this trivial case, but if you chain say 5 or 6 operations prior it'd be quite ugly (though not impossible) to write it in this way.

Answer (score 0):

With [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar), you can use the `f` pronoun:

```py
>>> from datar.all import f, tibble, filter, mutate, sum
>>> 
>>> tibble(x=3) >> filter(f.x==3) >> mutate(x=f.x/sum(f.x))
          x
  <float64>
0       1.0
```

I am the author of the package. Feel free to submit issues if you have any questions.